# Return min. and max. value simultaneously of an array using minimum number of comparisons

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, data-structures

```
struct Pair
{
    int min;
    int max;
};
 
struct Pair getMinMax(int arr[], int n)
{
    struct Pair minmax;    
    int i;
     
    // If array has even number of elements
    // then initialize the first two elements
    // as minimum and maximum
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        if (arr[0] > arr[1])    
        {
            minmax.max = arr[0];
            minmax.min = arr[1];
        }
        else
        {
            minmax.min = arr[0];
            minmax.max = arr[1];
        }
         
        // Set the starting index for loop
        i = 2;
    }
     
    // If array has odd number of elements
    // then initialize the first element as
    // minimum and maximum
    else
    {
        minmax.min = arr[0];
        minmax.max = arr[0];
         
        // Set the starting index for loop
        i = 1;
    }
     
    // In the while loop, pick elements in
    // pair and compare the pair with max
    // and min so far
    while (i < n - 1)
    {        
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])        
        {
            if(arr[i] > minmax.max)    
                minmax.max = arr[i];
                 
            if(arr[i + 1] < minmax.min)        
                minmax.min = arr[i + 1];    
        }
        else       
        {
            if (arr[i + 1] > minmax.max)    
                minmax.max = arr[i + 1];
                 
            if (arr[i] < minmax.min)        
                minmax.min = arr[i];    
        }
         
        // Increment the index by 2 as
        // two elements are processed in loop
        i += 2;
    }        
    return minmax;
}
 
// Driver code
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1000, 11, 445,
                1, 330, 3000 };
    int arr_size = 6;
     
    Pair minmax = getMinMax(arr, arr_size);
     
    cout << "nMinimum element is "
        << minmax.min << endl;
    cout << "nMaximum element is "
        << minmax.max;
         
    return 0;
}
```

In this qsn we have to return max and min value simultaneously so here struct is made.
I copied this code from GEEKSFORGEEKS site. I was trying this code's approach but stuck in doubt that how here comparisons is being calculates.
In this code i want to know that how comparisons is  3*(n-1)/2 when n=odd?

Comment: Are you not allowed to use [`std::minmax`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax)?

Comment: Blindly copying code tend to lead to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), which is rather bad. And generally code on that site tend to be very low quality, and sometimes even directly invalid. I wouldn't use it for anything serious, and especially not try to use any code from it.

Comment: *I copied this code from GEEKSFORGEEKS site* -- `struct Pair getMinMax(int arr[], int n)` -- This is proof that the site you copied this code from is not one to use if learning C++.  There is no need for the `struct` keyword there.  It looks like whoever wrote this code couldn't make up their mind if they were writing a `C` program or a C++ program.

Comment: The irony here is that all those initial comparisons related to even/odd array size add more complexity and possibly more comparisons than just a simple loop starting from 1. And the loop hopping 2 at a time is not saving a whole lot because you're already adding 1 to indices and performing three comparisons every step. This is far too niche of an optimization exercise IMO, and might lead people astray in terms of when code should be optimized in the first place. It sacrifices readability and simplicity to achieve 1.5N instead of 2N (worst-case) comparisons.

Comment: I imagine with all those extra branches this code will end up being slower even if it does theoretically use fewer comparisons. I certainly doubt the optimiser will be able to work out any simd or loop unrolling for this code

Comment: Aside: what's wrong with `std::pair` - no need to roll your own.  One of a million reasons why GFG sucks.

Comment: @Tanvi - About number of comparisons: The while-loop runs up to `n - 1` in steps of 2, so about `(n - 1) / 2` rounds (with minor variation for even or odd). Then it does 3 comparisons for each round - 1 outer if and 2 inner ones.

Comment: @BoP-Thank you sir,I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

The above code is the definition of premature optimization. Where you literally are taking the below code that takes 4 int compares per two elements, down to 3, and the cost of making the code hard to read, and easier to write bugs into.

Even in the code written below these could be changed to if() else if(), since they are populated with the same value to start with, both conditions are impossible to be true. But it's not worth making that change to make the reader have to think through if that is actually true.

Trying to be too smart, and you'll only outsmart yourself.

```
struct Pair
{
    int min;
    int max;
};
 
Pair getMinMax(int arr[], int length){
   Pair output = {0, 0};
   if(length < 1){
       return output;
   }
   output.min = arr[0];
   output.max = arr[0];
   
   for(int i= 1; i < length; i++){
       if(arr[i] < output.min){
           output.min = arr[i];
       }
        if(arr[i] > output.max){
           output.max = arr[i];
       }
   }

    return output;
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 8, 6, 4, 2, 9, 4};
    auto data = getMinMax(array, 6);

    std::cout << data.min << " " << data.max;
}
```

Comment: Replace  int arr[] with std::vector<int> for more maintainable and reusable code. Passing the size seperatly will at some moment become a bug.

Comment: @PepijnKramer thanks static analyzer-san. The idea was to illustrate the same style of code...

Comment: I understand that, but I think we can always teach an extra step. Specially if that step leads to a less painful programming experience :) And reusing tested code from STL is also part of not outsmarting yourself and keeping it simple.

Comment: @PepijnKramer It's a double edge sword, specially with new programmers. Add in too many API's they are not familiar with, then your answer is just something else they don't understand.

Comment: It is it is, but most classes start with teaching datastructures using C++ and all they learn is how to use new/delete,"C" style arrays. People tend to keep using what they learned first, and then think the rest is advanced. While it should be the other way around, build some succesful code with STL and then learn how to implement lower level things. The end result will be cleaner programs with less bugs which we require in industry (much more then people who can write low level libraries)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I feel like that's opinion based, with c and C++ learning the memory management is extremely important. I see skilled developers who program in higher level languages come into C++ and destroy themselves because they don't know how to deal with memory when a class isn't managing it for them.

Comment: it is opinion based, but there are many good arguments against teaching C++ as if it was C. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk

Comment: "...they don't know how to deal with memory when a class isn't managing it for them." I'd rather say: " because they don't know that classes are not supposed to manually manage memory. 99% is covered by containers and smart pointers and the rest is covered by custom classes that do nothing but manage memory, but you can go a long way in C++ before you actually need it"

Comment: @Natio2 I agree with the other comments here - learn about the STL up front, it will save a lot of pain later on.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using STL code (C++20) :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct MinMaxResult
{
    int min;
    int max;
};

MinMaxResult getMinMax(const std::vector<int>& values)
{
    return (values.size() == 0) ? 
        MinMaxResult{} : 
        MinMaxResult(std::ranges::min(values), std::ranges::max(values));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values{ 8, 6, 4, 2, 9, 4 };
    auto data = getMinMax(values);
    std::cout << data.min << ", " << data.max;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Like as a newbie programmer this would have confused me. What if they don't know what a turnary is? How to set there compiler to c++20? Then when it doesn't compile, don't know enough to notice you've made a mistake with your initializer list, and then to top it off with the endless rules someone comes along to say don't use .size() use .empty()

Comment: Why not use [`std::ranges::minmax`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/minmax) like `auto [min, max] = std::ranges::minmax(values)`? You are reinventing the wheel with your `MinMaxResult` class...

Comment: @Natio2 confusion is part of learning. If you never confront a beginner with something new they will never learn.

Comment: @JakobStark My still incomplete knowledge of ranges I think :) So yes that should be even cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

There are answers (good ones imho), but so far none does actually count the number of comparisons. With `std::minmax_element` you can count the number of comparisons like this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename TAG>
struct compare {
    static size_t count;
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T& a,const T& b){
        ++count;
        return a < b;
    }
};

template <typename TAG> size_t compare<TAG>::count = 0;

template <typename TAG>
compare<TAG> make_tagged_compare(TAG) { return {};}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x{1,2,3};

    auto c = make_tagged_compare([](){});
    auto mm = std::minmax_element(x.begin(),x.end(),c);
    std::cout << *mm.first << " " << *mm.second << " " << c.count;

}
```

Standard algorithms may copy predicates passed to them, hence `count` is `static`. Because I want to reuse `compare` later to count a different algorithm, I tagged it (each lambda expression is of different type, hence it can be used as unique tag). [The output is](https://godbolt.org/z/o48qd79vW):

```
1 3 3
```

It correctly finds min and max, 1 and 3, and needs 3 comparisons to achieve that.

Now if you want to compare this to a different algorithm, it will look very similar to the above. You pass a functor that compares elements and counts the number of comparisons of the algorithm. As example I use a skeleton implementation that does only a single comparison and either returns `{x[0],x[1]}` or `{x[1],x[0]}`:

```
template <typename IT, typename Compare> 
auto dummy_minmax(IT first, IT last,Compare c) {
    auto second = first+1;
    if (c(*first,*second)) return std::pair(*first,*second);
    else return std::pair(*second,*first);
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x{1,2,3};

    auto c = make_tagged_compare([](){});
    auto mm = std::minmax_element(x.begin(),x.end(),c);
    std::cout << *mm.first << " " << *mm.second << " " << c.count << "\n";

    double x2[] = {1.0,2.0,5.0};
    auto c2 = make_tagged_compare([](){});
    auto mm2 = dummy_minmax(std::begin(x2),std::end(x2),c2);
    std::cout << mm2.first << " " << mm2.second << " " << c2.count; 
}
```

[Complete example](https://godbolt.org/z/frvjvGvaY)